# angular-ui-grid: plus icon (expandable row) at left side - how to change it to right side

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, right-to-left, expandable

i am using ui-grid with the expandrow feature (
[demo from ui-grid site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWABA.png) ).

because my language is RTL so the plus icon displayed at the right side

i need that the position of the plus icon will be at the left side **(architecture request)**

any idea how can i do that

thank

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at the source code on github.

You should try editing the parameter:  **$scope.gridOptions.rowTemplate**.

If you check the file @ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angular-ui/bower-ui-grid/master/ui-grid.js , you will see:

> ```
>   /**
>    * @ngdoc string
>    * @name rowTemplate
>    * @propertyOf ui.grid.class:GridOptions
>    * @description 'ui-grid/ui-grid-row' by default. When provided, this setting uses a
>    * custom row template.  Can be set to either the name of a template file:
>    * <pre> $scope.gridOptions.rowTemplate = 'row_template.html';</pre>
>    * inline html
>    * <pre>  $scope.gridOptions.rowTemplate = '<div style="background-color: aquamarine" ng-click="grid.appScope.fnOne(row)" ng-repeat="col in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.colDef.name" class="ui-grid-cell" ui-grid-cell></div>';</pre>
>    * or the id of a precompiled template (TBD how to use this) can be provided.
>    * </br>Refer to the custom row template tutorial for more information.
>    */
>   baseOptions.rowTemplate = baseOptions.rowTemplate || 'ui-grid/ui-grid-row';
> ```